# I need help logging in to root

Tags: nautilus, sudo

Can somebody help me? I’m new to Ubuntu, and I need help elevating my privileges to root. All I’m getting is:

```
darion@darion-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo -i nautilus
[sudo] password for darion: 

(nautilus:3306): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.
Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

(nautilus:3306): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkMessageDialog' to 'NautilusWindow'
**
ERROR:nautilus-window.c:2116:nautilus_window_get_slots: assertion failed:(NAUTILUS_IS_WINDOW (window))
```

Comment: There is no root pasword in ubuntu.

Comment: You should be launching nautilus with `$ gksudo nautilus`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you `gksu` than `sudo` because `sudo` is not *GUI* sudo program, but `gksu` is it.

You can do it with following command.

```
gksu nautilus
```

If you had not install gksu, You must install it with following command.

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```